# Как получить текст в строке до первого слэша справа в Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток!

У меня в js-файле есть вот такие строки. Мне нужно получать из этих строк только названия картинок и расширения. То есть, мне нужен текст справа до первого слэша. Как мне его получить?

Вот такие строки:

```
assets/img/header/item.png
assets/img/header/item2.png
assets/img/why/lightning_bg_4x.png
assets/img/why/target_1.png
assets/img/case/case-2.png
assets/img/case/case-1.png
```

Благодарю за внимание

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let arr = [
    'assets/img/header/item.png',
    'assets/img/header/item2.png',
    'assets/img/why/lightning_bg_4x.png',
    'assets/img/why/target_1.png',
    'assets/img/case/case-2.png',
    'assets/img/case/case-1.png'
];


arr.forEach(item => {
    console.log(item.split('/').pop());
});
```

Comment: О, да, вот. Не мог додуматься))

Answer (score 2):

```js
const href = [
  'assets/img/header/item.png',
  'assets/img/header/item2.png',
  '/img///////header/item3.png',
  'item8.png',
]

for (let h of href){
  console.log(h.replace(/(.*\/)+/g, ''))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
[
  'assets/img/header/item.png assets/img/header/item2.png',
  'assets/img/why/lightning_bg_4x.png assets/img/why/target_1.png',
  'assets/img/case/case-2.png assets/img/case/case-1.png'
].forEach(e => {
  const a = e.split('/');
  console.log(a[a.length - 1]);
});
```